# How to send small message to microsoft message queue from BizTalk 2016?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I get the following error message when I try to send message to Microsoft Message Queue to server on the local network from BizTalk 2016 using the MSMQ adapter:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.MSMQ.MsmqLargeMessageWrapper.dll or one of
>   its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

BizTalk, BizTalk Adapter Packs and BizTalk Enterprise Adapters are installed, and I am able to configure send and receive handlers and the send port itself.

Are there any pre-requisities I need to install?

Not very often you google and find four irrelevant answers...so what am I not getting?

Comment: Did you install both the 32 and 64 bit versions of the Adapter?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes, of course. :)

Do I need to install Host Integration Server too...? I have not seen any documentation that says so, but I bounced into a forum discussing another error message...

Comment: No, I don't think you need HIS for MSMQ, HIS is for IBM connectivity, e.g.  WebSphere MQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. I was unlucky while I was thinking... ;|

MSMQ Adapter is built to call Windows Message Queuing queue on a Windows Server. If you call a remote queue, you need to activate Microsoft Messaging feature on the local server too - otherwise you end up with a simlar error message like above. It will forward the queue processing to the remote server.

Comment: And, Host Instances must be restarted.

Lycky me I exist!